# How to get cookie in nuxtServerInit()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am using `vue-cookie` package which lets me to set and get cookies with ease. What I want is to get this cookie in `nuxtServerInit()`:

```
async nuxtServerInit() {
   const res = await this.$axios.post('/me', {}, {
       headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $nuxt.$cookie.get('token')
       }
   })
}
```

But, I always get `$nuxt is not defined` error. Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

vue cookie is a wrapper around [tiny-cookie](https://github.com/Alex1990/tiny-cookie) . Tiny cookie is for browser. So it wont work on server e.g. in nuxtServerInit

In nuxtServerInit you should get cookies from req.cookies

```
async nuxtServerInit(_, { req }) {
   console.log(req.headers.cookie)
}
```

Comment: For me, req is undefined. I am unable to read cookies from inside the nuxtServerInit

Comment: @JohanVanWambeke what mode are you using nuxt in? [req](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-req-code-a-href-https-nodejs-org-api-http-html-http_class_http_incomingmessage-em-http-request-em-a-) will not be defined if you are using static mode with `nuxt generate`.